# How to refresh datagridview binding in vb.net or C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I created two tables(FIRSTtable and SECONDtable) in the mysql database and two tables that are related.

The FIRST table, has a columns (product_id (pK), product_name).
The SECOND table has an columns (machine_id, production_date, product_id (fK), 
product_quantity, operator_id).

Relations between the two tables using the product_id column with UpdateCascade and DeleteCascade. Both relationships are functioning normally when I try with the sql script. Suppose I delete all product_id in the FIRST table, all existing data in the SECOND table will be deleted.

Both of these tables displayed in datagridview. When I delete all the data in the FIRST table, the all rows in datagridview FIRST table will be deleted, also the data in mysql the FIRST table will be deleted.

I try to open the mysql database, the data are in SECOND Table also deleted, the problem why the view that in the second datagridview, can not be deleted, still keep the previous data? How to refresh datagridview binding in vb.net or C#? Thanks.

```
    With Me.SECOND_DataGridView
        .Datasource = Nothing  ' tried this, but failed.
        .DataSource = MyDataset.Tables("SECOND_table")
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are running into is the fact the the MySQL Engine is actually performing the cascading deletes for you.

When you query the MySQL Data into a localized C# "DataTable" (Table within a DataSet), that data is now in memory and not directly linked to that on the disk.  When you go to delete the rows in the "memory" version of the first data table, its causing the deletions to occur at the SERVER for the second level table and NOT directly updating you in-memory version of data table two.

That being said, you will probably have to do one of two things...  Requery the entire dataset (tables one and two) to get a full refresh of what is STILL in the actual database...  OR... As you are calling the delete from table one of the dataset, you'll have to perform the delete handling in the local datatable TWO as well to keep it in synch.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After deleting the data in the first datatable and delete data in the first table (disk), I do the clear datasets, and refill the dataset with a database that has just been updated and it is working now.

Comment: *I created a mysql database, tables and columns and the relations among them programmatically. After successfully doing that, then I put the database into a dataset, use the command **MyDataAdapter.Fill (MyDataset, valSch.Tables.TableName)** including the relationship between the table with the command **MyDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey**. Does this mean that the relation between the DataTable inside a Dataset, does not work?? Thanks

Comment: @wira yudha, I honestly can't answer that as I've not dealt with datasets and cascading deletes.  There might be some configurable relationship settings between them at the dataset level that contains both data tables, but again, I've never dealt with this specific element.